# Filter through a text file

Tags: ruby, text

I want to sort through a text file and leave only a certain section. I have this text in the text file:

```
{
  "id"=>”0000001”, 
  "type"=>”cashier”, 
  "summary"=>”Henock”, 
  "self"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000001”, 
  "html_url"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000001”
}

{
  "id"=>”0000002”, 
  "type"=>”cashier”, 
  "summary"=>”Vic”, 
  "self"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000002”, 
  "html_url"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000002”
}

{
  "id"=>”0000003”, 
  "type"=>”cashier”, 
  "summary"=>”Mo”, 
  "self"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003”, 
  "html_url"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003”
}
```

How would I sort it so that only the information with person `"Mo"` is shown?

This is what I tried:

```
somefile.readlines("filename.txt").grep /Mo}/i
```

but it is useless.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please show what you have already tried. Your question, as it currently is will probably not receive a good answer, and may be closed. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Comment: You may be able to "parse" it as JSON first then search through that...GL!

Comment: If that's well-formed JSON, which you can test [with a lint tool](https://jsonlint.com), then you can parse it with `JSON.load`. The problem there is there's sequential documents, so you'll need to split on blank lines. This also has malformed quotes, so if those are present in the original you'll need to fix them first.

Comment: At least in software context, I think the term *sort* is not used for what you have in mind here. Sort means to change the order of things in a list. Rather, you seem to want to *filter* or *select* the sections.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def retrieve_block(fname, summary_target)
  arr = []
  File.foreach(fname) do |line|
    next if line.strip.empty? 
    arr << line
    next unless arr.size == 7
    return arr.join if arr[3].match?(/\"summary\"=>\"#{summary_target}\"/)
    arr = []
  end
end
```

**Example**

Let's first create a file.

```
text =<<_
{
  "id"=>"0000001", 
  "type"=>"cashier", 
  "summary"=>"Henock", 
  "self"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000001", 
  "html_url"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000001"
}

{
  "id"=>"0000003", 
  "type"=>"cashier", 
  "summary"=>"Mo", 
  "self"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003", 
  "html_url"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003"
}
_
```

All of the keys and values represented in this string are surrounded with double-quotes. In the question however, many of these keys and values are surrounded by special characters that have a superficial appearance of a double quote. I have assumed that those characters would be converted to double quotes in a pre-processing step.

```
FName = "test"
File.write(FName, text)
  #=> 325

puts retrieve_block(FName, "Mo")
{
  "id"=>"0000003",
  "type"=>"cashier",
  "summary"=>"Mo",
  "self"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003",
  "html_url"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003"
}
```

This should work because of the consistent format of the file.

To return a hash, rather than a string, a slight modification is required.

```
def retrieve_block(fname, summary_target)
  h = {}
  File.foreach(fname) do |line|
    line.strip!
    next if line.empty? || line == '{'
    if line == '}'
      if h["summary"] == summary_target
        break h
      else
        h = {}
      end
    else
      k, v = line.delete('",').split("=>")
      h[k] = v
    end  
  end
end

retrieve_block(FName, "Mo")
  #=> {"id"=>"0000003",
  #    "type"=>"cashier",
  #    "summary"=>"Mo",
  #    "self"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003",
  #    "html_url"=>"https://google.com/accounts/0000003"}
```

Comment: Excuse me sir. I was wondering what are some useful ways that you learned how to code (Ruby)? I'm a complete novice and I've read that you liked to help people learn ruby.

Comment: I always recommend the [Core Ruby](http://courses.rubylearning.org/catalog?new=true) course at Ruby Learning". There you will get help and feedback from human instructors.

Comment: Thank you sir! One more question, what are your thoughts about Lynda?

Comment: I don't know anything about Lynda.